# Add a function using another function's parameter declaration

Tags: python

I am trying to add some customized logic outside of an existing function. Here are the example:

```
# existing function that I cannot change
def sum(a, b, c, d):
  return a+b+c+d

# the function I want to build
def sumMultiply(a, b, c, d, multiplier):
  return multiplier * sum(a, b, c, d)
```

This is a stupid example, but essentially I want to build a new function that takes all the parameter of the existing function and add a few new arguments.

The above solution is problematic when the existing function changes its definition. For example:

```
# in some updates the original function dropped one parameter
def sum(a, b, c):
  return a+b+c

# the new function will give an error since there is no parameter "d"
def sumMultiply(a, b, c, d, multiplier):
  return multiplier * sum(a, b, c, d) # error
```

How can I specify the new function so that I do not need to worry about changing the new function definition when the existing function definition changes?

Comment: Not convinced this is doable.  You might handle 1 less argument, as per example.  How about renamed arguments?  Extra arguments?  `sumMultiply`‘s signature or its call to existing would need to change, would they not?  If sumMultiply’s sig changes then the client code will be affected.  I’d write up a solid test suite exercising all bits of the existing API you care about.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use arbitrary positional or keyword arguments:

```py
def sumMultiply(multiplier, *numbers):
    return multiplier * sum(*numbers)

def sumMultiply(multiplier, *args, **kwargs):
    return multiplier * sum(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, if you see yourself passing around the same set of data around, consider making a [parameter object](https://wiki.c2.com/?ParameterObject). In your case, it can simply be a list:

```py
def sum(numbers):
    ...

def sumMultiply(multiplier, numbers):
    return multiplier * sum(numbers)
```

There are some additional downsides to using arbitrary arguments:

- the arguments are implicit: you might need to dig through several layers to see what you actually need to provide
- they don't play well with type annotations and other static analysers (e.g. PyCharm's refactorings)

Comment: Thanks! Are there anyway we can know what the arguments are in `sumMultiply`?

For example, we want to add 1 to argument `a` in  `sumMultiply` instead of just passing them in to `sum` function.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a [decorator function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator)

```py
def create_fun_multiplier(fun, multiplier=1):
    def multiplier_fun(*args):
        return multiplier * fun(*args)
    return multiplier_fun

def my_sum(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c

sumMultiply = create_fun_multiplier(my_sum, multiplier=2)
print(sumMultiply(3, 4, 7))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using keyword args for this problem.

eg.

```
def sum(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c

def sumMultiply(*args, multiplier=1):
    return multiplier * sum(*args)
```